# Counting points contained in polygon for large number of points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, large-datasets

I'm trying to determine the number of points within a set of polygons for a large number of points. There are 2GB of lat-long coordinates in a CSV file, and I want to see how many are contained in each polygon.

The number of points seems too large to import as a layer of points and then do a spatial join.

Is there any alternative that works well with large datasets?

Comment: On the contrary, the file is too large to **not** load into a spatial dataset (FGDB or Enterprise GDB), spatially index, and query ***with the polygons***.

Comment: What happens when you load your points into a file geodatabase and try this?

Comment: I tried this and at the stage where I do the spatial join, it stops in the middle without completing it and does not give an error message. There are roughly 16 million observations.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, and the size of the data size was not an issue. I think the problem was that I imported the GPS data in the wrong coordinate system. I also did some data cleaning before I imported the data again. A few observations had missing data.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is not a spatial dataset, it is nothing more than a comma separated text file. The only structure it has is the comma.

As the other commentators indicate you need to import it into a geodatabase. 2GB is well within their limits and once in as a spatial dataset with spatial indexing you could easily answer this question with a spatial Join.

Also EXCEL is not a spatial format either!